# Provide a link to the "main" chat room for each SE site

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, chat, stackexchange-2.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should the 'chat' link of a SE 2.0 site take you to the site specific chat room?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68920/should-the-chat-link-of-a-se-2-0-site-take-you-to-the-site-specific-chat-room)

Currently the chat sidebar only lists room with recent activity belonging to the site, but not the general chat for that site - a popular room most (if not all) SE-2.0 sites have.

This means that new users looking for chat might have to wade through the busy chat lobby to find the general chat room for their site, if they can find it at all - some room names are far from obvious (for example "Bridge" is the main gaming room and "Root Access" is the main super user room - clever names but it's not obvious what those rooms are).

I suggest that the UI be changed to point directly at the general chat room for that site - for example, change the "chat" link in the top bar to point directly to that room. It's easy to get to the chat lobby from within a room. But that's just a suggestion - any way to directly link to the main room will be good.

Comment: +1 I approve this message