# Clicking 'chat' from the SuperCollider™ no longer takes you to to a site specific chat page

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, stack-exchange-button

See below for a video of what I tried

https://youtu.be/JNK77izecBs

I'm used to this link taking need to site specific chat page.

I found:

[Should the 'chat' link of a SE 2.0 site take you to the site specific chat room?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68920/175002)

But it's old and unhelpful.

Is this a bug? A feature? Should it be changed?

I'm on Android 4.something, with chrome browser, if it helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chrome on Android doesn't pass referer data between domains; it appears to behave the same way as Chrome Desktop does for HTTPS requests, but for *all* requests.

Since that chat link depends on the referer header to determine which site you're coming from... It never works on mobile.

Marc Gravell fixed this in response to this post (see comments below).

Comment: An easier fix would be to use the host query string instead of relying on referrer. Pretty sure that was proposed at some point, but we never got around to it.

Comment: @Adam and amusingly, the actual page has always supported it - just `?host={whatever.com}`; taking a look to see how easy we can fix this

Comment: The host should be explicit in future builds

Comment: @marcgravell is this really completed already?

Comment: @PureFerret give or take a deploy, yes, it should work (I've checked, and at the current time it is still in the pending build queue; I don't have a strong reason to rush it through, but: it should work very soon - we usually deploy multiple times every week-day)

Comment: @Marc since you mentioned this, how this "build queue" works? Are there  any automatic deploys, or is this done only manually by a dev?

Comment: @Shadow automatic to our dev / validation tier, then one button (whenever we want) to push to meta.SO / meta.SE for final smoke test, and one button to push to everywhere else. We work on a "if you aren't happy for it to go to production without you knowing, don't commit it to 'master'" basis.

Comment: @Marc thanks. So when enough changes are made, someone push that button, where "enough" can be defined by any of the team individually? (or is this decision only made by "high ranked" dev"?)

Comment: @Shadow we don't worry much about things like rank. Anyone on the team has authority to do that, unless someone has explicitly communicated the need for a planned / complicated deploy (and hopefully marked the build server as such, and pinned a message in our team chat)

Comment: This still seems broken

Comment: Seems to work for me, @Pureferret. Note that unless your filter is set to "site", you'll still see all rooms but site rooms will sort first.